# ошибка The operator <= is undefined for the argument type(s) darts, int

Tags: java

Я столкнулся с одной проблемой. Когда я сравниваю числа в if выходит ошибка: The operator <= is undefined for the argument type(s) darts, int.

Вот код if:

```
if (d1 <= 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have earned 1 point!");
            } else if (d1 <= 3) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have earned 3 point!");
            } else if (d1 <= 5) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have earned 5 point!");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lost!");
            }
```

Весь код:

```
JButton enterButton = new JButton("Enter");
        enterButton.setBounds(239, 239, 97, 25);
        contentPane.add(enterButton);
        enterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String oneThrow = firstThrow.getText().trim();
            String twoThrow = secondThrow.getText().trim();
            System.out.println(oneThrow + " " + twoThrow);
            double x = Double.parseDouble(oneThrow);
            double y = Double.parseDouble(twoThrow);
            darts d1 = new darts(x, y);
            if(oneThrow.isEmpty() || twoThrow.isEmpty()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Пожалуйста введите значения в поля.");
            }
            if (d1 <= 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have earned 1 point!");
            } else if (d1 <= 3) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have earned 3 point!");
            } else if (d1 <= 5) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have earned 5 point!");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lost!");
            }
            
        }
        });
```

Код darts(), который я использовал в вышеупомянутом коде:

```
public class darts {
    private double res;
    public darts(double x, double y) {
        res = x + y;
    }
```

Как исправить эту ошибку? Спасибо заранее.

Comment: ну а что вы хотите? вы сравниваете darts с int

Comment: а оно не хочет сравниваться. А вобще у darts только double

Comment: Конечно не хочет сравниваться. Что вы хотели сделать данным сравнением?

Comment: а у меня 2 руки; я меньше 3-х?

Comment: есть два значения x и y которые принимают значения JTextField oneThrow и twoThrow. x и y должны складываться и получается d1. Потом идет сравнение в которым выясняется сколько дается очков за оба броска.

Comment: @SamSamovich ну так сравнивайте поле res, а не сам объект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class darts {

    private double res;

    public darts(double x, double y) {
            res = x + y;
    }

    public double  getRes() {
        return res;
    }
 }

И сравнивайте - (d1.getRes() <= 1)
```

Классы и конструкторы принято писать с большой буквы, рекомендую переименовать darts в Darts.

Comment: огромное спасибо! Помогло